# Woocommerce change default order [method - price] shipping en CART

Tags: woocommerce

wc-cart-functions.php

```
function wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) {
    $label = $method->label;

    if ( $method->cost > 0 ) {
        if ( WC()->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
            $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
                $label .= ' <small>' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        } else {
            $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() );
            if ( $method->get_shipping_tax() > 0 && ! WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
                $label .= ' <small>' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
            }
        }
    } elseif ( $method->id !== 'free_shipping' ) {
        $label .= ' (' . __( 'Free', 'woocommerce' ) . ')';
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', $label, $method );
}
```

The function returns `$label`, `$method` and I want to show `$method`, `$label`

Change the order is not possible

I want to change the order of [ price - shipping method]  since the system shows [ shipping method - price]

Currently, the CHECKOUT page looks like this:

```
        Cart Subtotal  $300.00
        Shipping  **Ship To An International Destination: $35.00** *CHANGE*
        Order Total $335.00
```

As I could change the CHECKOUT page to look like this;

```
       Cart Subtotal           $300.00
       Shipping and Handling   **$35.00 Ship To An International Destination** *CHANGE*
       Order Total             $335.00
```

Comment: cart-shipping.php


I just found the solution, the return of this function, wp_kses_post( wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) );  I just used a separator with the split function to change the order of appearance. 

 
<?php if ( 1 === count( $available_methods ) ) :
$method = current( $available_methods );
$Leyenda=wp_kses_post( wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) );
$palabras=split(":","$Leyenda");
echo "$palabras[1] $palabras[0]"; 
?> 

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In cart-shipping.php

I just found the solution, the return of this function,

```
wp_kses_post( wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) );
```

I just used a separator with the split function to change the order of appearance.

```
<?php if ( 1 === count( $available_methods ) ) : $method = current( $available_methods  );    $Leyenda=wp_kses_post( wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) );                 $palabras=split(":","$Leyenda"); echo "$palabras[1] $palabras[0]"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just change:

```
 $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost );
```

to

```
 $label = wc_price( $method->cost ) . ': ' . $label ;
```

also change :

```
 $label .= ': ' . wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() );
```

to

```
$label = wc_price( $method->cost + $method->get_shipping_tax() ) . ' : ' .$label;
```

Hope can help someone with same question in the future :)